# What is the right way to insert DBGeography type via ado.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, sqlgeography

I am trying to insert `DBGeography` type via ado.net but no luck.
This is the errors that I am getting:

> No mapping exists from object type
>   System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography to a known managed provider
>   native type.

or:

> Specified type is not registered on the target
>   server.System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography, EntityFramework,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.

This is what I do when I am getting it from db and this works fine:

```
dynamic temp = reader.GetValue(3);

                var text = string.Format("POINT({0:R} {1:R})", temp.Long, temp.Lat);
                var srid = temp.STSrid.Value;
                this.Coordinates = System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.PointFromText(text, srid);
```

But insert doesn't work:

```
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Coordinates", store.Coordinates);
// or ...
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter();
                    p.ParameterName = "@Coordinates";
                    p.Value = store.Coordinates;
                    p.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Udt;
                    p.UdtTypeName = "geography";
                    updateCommand.Parameters.Add(p);
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061227/no-mapping-exists-from-object-type-system-data-spatial-dbgeography-to-a-known-ma

Comment: I have tried all solutions here from stackverflow but none worked

Comment: From the error "Specified type is not registered on the target server", it appears that some package is missing. Did you try re-installing?

Did you check this link? - https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/646

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Could you try using the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types instead of System.Data.Entity....

Comment: You can avoid all the guesswork building your command by using [SqlCommandBuilder](https://imgur.com/dcdUVyE). Likewise, you can avoid all the ugliness of string manipulation by using [SqlGeographyBuilder](https://imgur.com/dcdUVyE). Sorry for the double link...:O)

Comment: Hi, I am facing the below exception while adding SQLGeography type as SQL command.parameter to store procedue.                           `Specified type is not registered on the target server.Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography`   
                                                                                   `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@deviceGeolocation", SqlDbType.Udt) { UdtTypeName = "Geography", Value = geo, });` [issue link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205007/specified-type-is-not-registered-on-the-target-server-microsoft-sqlserver-types)

Answer (score 11):

`DbGeography` is a type that designed for `EntityFramework` not `ADO.NET`. Try to parse a Well Know Text Module to `SqlGeography` by [SqlGeography.Parse(SqlString)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.parse?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0#Microsoft_SqlServer_Types_SqlGeography_Parse_System_Data_SqlTypes_SqlString_) method, this should fix your problem.

```
dynamic temp = reader.GetValue(3);
var text = string.Format("POINT({0:R} {1:R})", temp.Long, temp.Lat);
var coordinate= SqlGeography.Parse(text );

SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter();
                 p.ParameterName = "@Coordinates";
                 p.Value = coordinate;
                 p.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Udt;
                 p.UdtTypeName = "geography";

updateCommand.Parameters.Add(p);
```

TL;DR:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/modules/well-known-text-module

> Well Known Text (WKT) is an Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) standard
>   that is used to represent spatial data in a textual format. Most
>   OGC-compliant systems support Well Known Text. Spatial functionality
>   in SQL Server 2008, 2012, and SQL Azure can easily convert between a
>   spatial object in the database and WKT. A WKT can only store the
>   information for a single spatial object and this spatial data format
>   is usually used as part of a larger file format or web service
>   response. The following are examples of each of the geometry types
>   represented as Well Known Text and the equivalent Bing Maps class that
>   is generated when parsing a Well Known Text string.

[image: Wellknown text module]

Comment: I am facing below issue while implementing this approach... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205007/specified-type-is-not-registered-on-the-target-server-microsoft-sqlserver-types

Answer (score 1):

Add those ASSEMBLIES 
 System.Data.SqlClient; System.Data.SqlTypes; System.Data.SqlServer.Types;

I think Geography is wrong(lower case).

**extents.UdtTypeName = "Geography";**

*p.UdtTypeName = "geography";*
 or Location = DbGeography.FromText("POINT(-122.360 47.656)")

Try this

```
public void InsertArea(string nameParameter, string extentsString)
{
       SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(...)

       sqlConn.Open();

       SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO areas (name, extents) VALUES (@name, @extents)", sqlConn);

       sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameParameter);

       SqlParamater extents = new SqlParameter("@extents", SqlDbType.Udt);
       extents.UdtTypeName = "Geography";
       extents.Value = GetGeographyFromText(extentsString);

       sqlCom.Parameters.Add(extents);

       sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();

       sqlConn.Close();
}

public SqlGeography GetGeographyFromText(String pText)
{
       SqlString ss = new SqlString(pText);
       SqlChars sc = new SqlChars(ss);
       try
       {
           return SqlGeography.STPolyFromText(sc, 4326);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
}


 string areaName = "Texas";
       string extents = string.Format("POLYGON(({0} {1}, {0} {2}, {3} {2}, {3} {1}, {0} {1}))", leftLongitude, upperLatitude, lowerLatitude, rightLongitude));

       InsertArea(areaName, extents);
```